# Use output of concat function as a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I don't want to write a macro (due to end user restrictions). I want the output of something like `=CONCAT("='",A2,"'!K14")` to be used as `='Sheet1'!K14`. This doesn't happen unless i explicitly go into the cell & hit a enter.

Comment: `=INDIRECT(CONCAT("'",A2,"'!K14"))`

Comment: Thanks. This worked. please post it as an answer so I can close this.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you are aware of the performance limits with Indirect.

It is a volatile function, meaning it calculates every time there is a change to the workbook. Not a problem when you use it a couple of times, but will probably freeze up if you have thousands of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Indirect Function. You can also simplify by replacing the CONCAT() function with just the AND operator. Try this:

`=INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!K14")`